# Differentiate $\displaystyle y = a^{x ^{a^{x^\cdots}}}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, infinite-product

Could anyone help with this question:

[image]

Edit: Reducing it to one of these options would be great!

Comment: Think of $y$ as being defined by the implicit equation $\,y = a^{x^y}\,$.

Comment: Disregarding any questions of convergence, you would have $\log(\log(y)) = y\log(x) + \log(\log(a))$. Then using implicit differentiation we have $\frac{y'}{y\log(y)} = y' \log(x) + \log(\log(a))$. Then $y' = \frac{y\log(y)\log(\log(a))}{1 - y\log(y)\log(x)}$

Comment: Is it $a$ raised to a chain of $x$ copies, or $a^{x}$ raised by a chain of $a^{x}$ copies?

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in my implicit differentiation... You get $\frac{y'}{y\log(y)} = y'\log(x) + \frac{y}{x}$ and so $y' = \frac{y^2\log(y)}{x(1 - y\log(y)\log(x))}$

Comment: It's $a^{x}$ copies.

Comment: @dxiv Is it $a^{x^y}$ or $(a^x)^y$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The posted expression is [usually parsed as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Special_cases) $a^{(x^{(y)})}=a^{x^y}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv That's what I think, too.  So none of the options is a correct answer and Tob's second comment gives the right answer

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I haven't followed the question since it was edited and answered. Tob's result looks right, indeed. Whether it might reduce to one of the given choices (which is still a possibility, since it's an implicit equation), that I haven't checked.

Comment: @dxiv I only now saw Tob's comment, and the result is indeed right. I gave the details in my answer. It seems unlikely that it would reduce to any of the options; it seems impossible to me to get rid of both $\log(y)$ and $\log(x)$.

Comment: The question was incorrectly printed. Sorry for the trouble..

Comment: No trouble man. As it was incorrectly printed I learned a new thing from @JoonasIlmavirta :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that everything is well defined and real, not paying attention to whether logarithms are taken of positive numbers and such.

We have $y=a^{x^y}$ (not $y=(a^x)^y$ which would mean $y=a^{{xa}^{{xa}^{\cdots}}}$).
Let me denote the derivative operator by $D$.

First we need a little lemma:
If $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$, then
$$
D(f^g)
=
De^{g\log(f)}
=
e^{g\log(f)}D(g\log(f))
=
f^g(g'\log(f)+gf'/f).
$$
(There is an easy way to memorize this. If $f$ is constant, the derivative is $f^g\log(f)g'$. If $g$ is constant, the derivative is $gf^{g-1}$. The full derivative is the sum of these two. This argument can be formalized, but it'd be a sidetrack here.)

Applying this to $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=y(x)$ gives
$$
D(x^y)
=
x^y(y'\log(x)+y/x).
$$
This will be useful soon.

Taking the derivative gives
\begin{align}
y'
&=
D(a^{x^y})
\\&=
a^{x^y}\log(a)D(x^y)
\\&=
y\log(a)D(x^y)
%\\&=
%y\log(a)[yx^{y-1}+\log(x)x^yy']
\\&=
y\log(a)x^y[y/x+\log(x)y']
\\&=
y\log(a^{x^y})[y/x+\log(x)y']
\\&=
y\log(y)[y/x+\log(x)y']
.
\end{align}
This gives
$$
[1-\log(x)y\log(y)]y'
=
y^2\log(y)/x,
$$
from which we can solve
$$
y'=\frac{y^2\log(y)}{x[1-\log(x)y\log(y)]}.
$$
This does not seem to match any of the options given.
Here is an alternative form, using $x^y=\log(y)/\log(a)$:
$$
y'=\frac{y^2\log(y)}{x\left[1-\log\left(\frac{\log(y)}{\log(a)}\right)\log(y)\right]}.
$$

Perhaps I miss a way to manipulate the formula, or perhaps the problem is mistaken; as others have pointed out, taking $y=(a^x)^y$ leads to option C.

Comment: Thanks for this lemma: $D(f^g)=De^{g\log(f)}=e^{g\log(f)}D(g\log(f))=f^g(g'\log(f)+gf'/f)$; I've done many derivatives but didn't come across this simple little trick, really appreciate this  :)

Comment: @k.Vijay You are welcome! :) That's actually an example of a more general method of differentiation, which makes differentiation of almost any function easy. This general thing is essentially my parenthetical remark after the lemma: you can treat different functions or instances of $x$ as constants in a certain way.

Comment: yes, this is more generalization which helps to solve problem like this (when both are variable), btw using this generalization we can do any kind of differentiation of exponential function...

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
y&=a^{x^{a^{x\cdots}}}\\
\implies y&=a^{x^y}\\
\implies \ln y&=x^y\ln a\hspace{25pt}\cdots\text{(i)}\\
\implies \dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=\ln a\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^y\right)\\
 &=\ln a\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^{y\ln x}\right)\\
&=\ln a\cdot e^{y\ln x}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(y\ln x)\\
&=\ln a\cdot x^y\cdot\left(\dfrac{y}{x}+\ln x\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)\\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}&=y\cdot x^y\ln a\cdot\left(\dfrac{y}{x}+\ln x\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)\\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}\left(1-y\cdot x^y\ln a\cdot\ln x\right)&=\dfrac{y^2}{x}\cdot x^y\ln a\\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}\left(1-y\cdot\ln y\cdot\ln x\right)&=\dfrac{y^2}{x}\cdot\ln y\hspace{25pt}\text{ as from (i) }[x^y\ln a=\ln y]\\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}&=\dfrac{y^2\ln y}{x\left(1-y\cdot\ln y\cdot\ln x\right)}
\end{align*}
So, this doesn't matches any answer.

Comment: You've made a mistake in the second line; I've corrected that.

Comment: ohh .. yes yes .. thanks for that :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Should not it be $\displaystyle a^{x^{y}}$ in the second line not $a^{xy}$ ?

Comment: ohoo..!!! I've made a huge mistake, thanks for pointing this out @A---B, let  me try to fix this

Comment: @k.Vijay Yes you should fix your answer even if it does not matches the answer in the book.

Comment: I've fixed it :) @A---B

Answer (score 0):

Building blocks:
$$
 D\left( a^{t(x)}, x\right) = a^x \ln (a) t'(x), \qquad
 D\left( x^x, x\right) = x^x (1 + \ln(x))
$$

First chains
$$
\begin{align}
  D\left( a^{x}, x\right) &= a^x \ln (a) \\
  D\left( a^{x^{x}}, x\right) &= x^x a^{x^x} \ln (a) (\ln (x)+1) \\
 D\left( a^{x^{x^{x}}}, x\right)&= a^{x^{x^x}} x^{x^x}  \ln (a) \left(x^{x-1}+x^x \ln (x) (\ln (x)+1)\right) \\
  D\left( \left( \left( \left( a^x \right)^x \right)^x \right)^x, x \right)
&= \left(\left(\left(a^x\right)^x\right)^x\right)^x \left(x \left(x \left(\ln \left(a^x\right)+x \ln (a)\right)+\ln \left(\left(a^x\right)^x\right)\right)+\ln \left(\left(\left(a^x\right)^x\right)^x\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: OP's question is *not* about $a^{x^{\color{red}{x}^\cdots}}$.